# Update canvas drawing on click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling

I'm trying to increase the radius of a circle drawn in canvas using JavaScript functions.

There were many topics with similar issues but couldn't find an answer that would fix this one, I've tried using built-in methods that were suggested like `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, `window.requestAnimationFrame` and clearing the canvas to redraw the circle with the updated variable.

So far the `setInterval` method displayed the update but kept the previous iterations in the canvas, the clear method doesn't work.

Here's the example :

```js
//Define globals
var radiusIncrement = 5;
var ballRadius = 20;

//Helper functions
function increaseRadius() {
  ballRadius += radiusIncrement;
}

function decreaseRadius() {
  if (ballRadius > 0) {
    ballRadius -= radiusIncrement;
  }
}


//Draw handler
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.height/2,canvas.width/2,ballRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

//Event handler
setInterval(function() {
  draw();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}, 100);
```

```html
<!--Create frame and assign callbacks to event handlers-->
<button type="button" onclick="increaseRadius()">Increase Radius</button>
<button type="button" onclick="decreaseRadius()">Decrease Radius</button>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Rather than using setInterval, is there a way to streamline the code using and use an event handler to refresh the canvas on every onlick ?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to redraw on the button click, i.e. on a radius change. You don't need any timing functions for this, you can call the draw function whenever a radius change happens:

```
//Define globals
var radiusIncrement = 5;
var ballRadius = 20;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//initialize
draw();

//Helper functions
function increaseRadius() {
  ballRadius += radiusIncrement;
  draw();
}

function decreaseRadius() {
  if (ballRadius > 0) {
    ballRadius -= radiusIncrement;
    draw();
  }
}


//Draw handler
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.height/2,canvas.width/2,ballRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

As you can see I also extracted the variable definition for `canvas` and `ctx` out of the draw function, since you don't need to re-assign these on every `draw` call.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot Mauro, that's the kind of streamlined solution I was looking for. Somehow the ball disappears near 0, it should be an easy fix. :D

Comment: Hi Mauro, actually it works, it's just so small it disappears under radius 5 ;)

Comment: Awesome,  glad I could help!